# Images not displaying in WebKit based browsers

Tags: html, webkit

For some strange, bizarre reason, my images in my website just will not display on webkit based languages (such as safari and chrome).

This is the image tag

```
<img src="images/dukkah.jpg" class="imgleft"/>
```

Not only does it not display in the website, it wont display when accessed directly at `http://kilkin.massiveatom.com/kilkin/images/dukkah.jpg`

...Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagemagick reports that this particular image is saved in CMYK colorspace instead of the more standard RGB. Try converting it, it should be more compatible with the webkit rendering engine.

Imagemagick is available for download from http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php - it's available for windows and *NIX systems.

Answer (score 2):

I have come across this problem a couple of times.

I think it is because of some problem in the file format.

Try importing the file in some image editor and saving it again. This should get rid of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the url you gave in FireFox 3 and IE 6, IE 6 won't show it either, firefox works. My guess is that there is something wrong with the jpg file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you JPEG's compressed in Jpeg 2000 Format? If so, there is a known bug:

- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=8754

Answer (score 0):

"The image “http://kilkin.massiveatom.com/kilkin/images/dukkah.jpg” cannot be displayed, because it contains errors." and the image itself has some XML-fragment in it. So as others proposed: try to open with an editor and resave it.

Answer (score 0):

It's as stated elsewere a bug in the image.

[Irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/) is a very good viewer that will display any image (and other formats as well), is small and free and will also let you adjust, crop or rescale images very easily without heavy programs like photoshop.

I suggest [download irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/main_download_engl.htm) and the image, open the image in irfanview and hit CTRL+S and save it over itself. Then upload the image again. Any problem should be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Your image file does not contain image data, it contains html text:

```
$ curl -s http://kilkin.massiveatom.com/kilkin/images/dukkah.jpg
<html><head></head><body><!-- vbe --></body></html>
```